# Overwrite Object function didn't affect {} expression?

Tags: javascript, object

I overwrite the Object constructor:

```
function Object() {
    console.log("here");
}
```

when I call `var x = new Object();`, I can see "here".
However, when I call `var x = {};`, I can't got it.
Isn't `{}` the same as `new Object()`? How can I get this work?

Answer (score 0):

using object() creates new function with name object with scope on document object, actually does not override object. While using var x = {}, it use original JS object.